# Converting VS 2010 solution to VS 2012 Linker errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to convert VS 2010 solution on VS 2012.

```
typedef const pair (const ustring, ustring) implv;
```

This line of code exists in two different cpp files of the same project. In VS 2010 it works seamlessly but in 2012 gives error as "one or more multiply defined symbols found." Any pointers? Error as follows:

error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall wrapped_iterator > > >,struct std::pair const >::wrapped_iterator > > >,struct std::pair const >(class std::_Tree_const_iterator > > >)" (??0?$wrapped_iterator@V?$_Tree_const_iterator@V?$_Tree_val@U?$_Tree_simple_types@U?$pair@$$CBVustring@@V1@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@$$CBU?$pair@$$CBVustring@@V1@@2@@@QAE@V?$_Tree_const_iterator@V?$_Tree_val@U?$_Tree_simple_types@U?$pair@$$CBVustring@@V1@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in wci_map_ustr_ustr.obj    File :wci_mmap_ustr_ustr.obj

Comment: What is a pair? Is it std::pair? Are you sure that after pair followed by a bracket? Please write the full text of error. And the description of other errors if they exist.

Comment: Yes it is a std pair.Somehow stackoverflow didn't allow <> followed by pair so had to use bracket there. Have edited the question with full text error. I am getting multiple errors similar to this.

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code to insert code block with formatting and correct symbols

Comment: It's not about the typedef - a typedef can't possibly trigger a linker error. The error complains about the constructor `wrapped_iterator::wrapped_iterator(set<implv>::const_iterator)` (or similar; I'm not sure about the parameter) being multiply defined. Have you, by any chance, defined a template specialization in a header file? Don't do that. Function template specializations aren't actually templates (they don't have any unbound template parameters left) but regular functions, and follow the same rules: you declare one in a header, and define it in the source file.